# Why is the program giving the same output every time?

Tags: c, structure

The program is to take input of various data about an employee in form of a structure. The program should then ask the current date from the user. If the difference between the years is more than 3 years the program should print the details of that employee. I wrote the following code for the same. The input of the date is taken in the form of a string and then the year characters are converted to corresponding integer. Please find the error in the respective code. The runtime of the program is given below.

RUNTIME -

```
For how many employees you want to enter the data for?
2
Enter the code, name and date of joining(Format is dd/mm/yyyy).
04 sukrit 02/09/1998
Enter the code, name and date of joining(Format is dd/mm/yyyy).
05 harish 02/05/2018
please enter the current date.(dd/mm/yyyy)
23/07/2019
4 sukrit 02/09/19985 harish 02/05/2018
```

PROGRAM -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void linkfloat();
struct employee
{
    int code; char name[10]; char date[10];
}n[20];
int main()
{
    int x,i,dh,y1,y2,diff;
    printf("For how many employees you want to enter the data for?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the code, name and date of joining(Format is dd/mm/yyyy).\n");
        scanf("%d %s %s",&n[i].code,n[i].name,n[i].date);
        while((dh=getchar())!='\n')
            ;
    }
    char cdate[10];
    printf("please enter the current date.(dd/mm/yyyy)\n");
    scanf("%s",cdate);
    //converting character to integer
    //date1
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        y1 = (n[i].date[6]-48)*1000+(n[i].date[7]-48)*100+(n[i].date[8]-48)*10+(n[i].date[9]-48);
        y2 = (cdate[6]-48)*1000+(cdate[7]-48)*100+(cdate[8]-48)*10+(cdate[9]-48);
        printf("%d %d\n",y1,y2);
        diff = abs(y2-y1);
        if(diff>=3)
        {
            printf("%d %s %s\n",n[i].code,n[i].name,n[i].date);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void linkfloat()
{
    float a=0,*n;
    n  = &a;
    a = *n;
}
```

Comment: What is the intention of `linkfloat`?

Comment: @Bathsheba To link the floating point formats, and so as to avoid that error.

Comment: But `a` and `b` are both automatic variables; the function is a no-op.

Comment: You have some memory errors.  Your date strings have 10 characters plus a terminating null character, so require a minimum of 11 character, yet you are only allocating space for 10.  And I don't see any checks in the code to catch strings that don't fit.  Fix that first.

Comment: Have you considered using C compiler that is not 30 years old?

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah got it chnaged b to n

Comment: You should remove `linkfloat` from the post.  It's not called, and it doesn't do anything.  See the guidelines for posting a *minimal* complete example.

Comment: @Bathsheba http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html

Comment: Actually i am using linux terminal and not turbo or any old compilers. The book i am reading had mentioned to do that and that's why i did it. Anyways thanks for the advice

Comment: OK, I revise my comment: Have you considered using a C book that is not 30 years old? :-)

Comment: @melpomene Yeah got you :P. Just doing some basic C from it. Going on for 'The C Programming Language by D. Ritchie'. Hope that is good!

Comment: @TomKarzes Did that but still getting the same output.

Comment: What is "link the floating point formats," supposed to mean? How are formats linked?

Comment: If you ever get an end-of-file without a preceding newline character, this will be an infinite loop:  `while((dh=getchar())!='\n') ;`

Comment: @Gerhardh http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html

Comment: @melpomene Ah. It's about linking libraries for floating point support. OK. Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char date[10];
```

Can hold max `9` char excluding `null` termination. But you are entering `10` chars giving no space for `\0` char.

```
02/09/1998
```

---

Thus your `printf` go on printing until it finds `\0` and invokes undefined behavior.

Change the size to.

```
char date[11];
```

and

```
char cdate[11];
```